# Is there a way to store a lambda function into a variable

Tags: java, lambda

I have a class that represents a game action. Every instance of this class should take a Game object in input (containing the game's state) and perform an action. For example if two players make a trade, the action should take the money from a player and give them to the other player, and then exchange the item. Since there are too many possible actions that one can do in a game, it would be nice to have a generic class that implements all kinds of actions, that stores a lambda function that executes such action. For example:

```
public class GameAction
{
    <lambda-function> action;
    public void doAction(Game game) {
        action(game); // e.g.: exchange money and items between two players
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do a similar thing in Java 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you could have a [`Consumer<Game>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/Consumer.html). This is a functional interface whose goal is to take a `Game` as argument and return no result: it effectively *consumes* the argument.

```
public class GameAction
{
    private Consumer<Game> action;
    public void doAction(Game game) {
        action.accept(game); // e.g.: exchange money and items between two players
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `GameAction` is essentially a `Consumer<Game>`. So you could write something like this:

```
Consumer<Game> exchangeAction = MyClass::exchangeAction;

private static void exchangeAction(Game game) {
    double amount = game.getAmount();
    game.getBuyer().spend(amount);
    game.getSeller().receive(amount);
}
```

With more context the example could be adapted to your need.